# Script to Duplicate and Rename an Image file from CSV info

Tags: shell-script

I have a base image that I'd like to use as an invisible image in a layout. I need to have the script duplicate `blank_image.png` and rename the copy using a column from my CSV data.

`blank_image.png` becomes:

```
abernathy_r.png
brown_p.png
crowder_l.png
```

...etc.

Is there way to do this and create an Apple Automator program to choose the image and to choose the data file?

Comment: Well, give us an example of your CSV file first

Comment: @DavidJashi Here is a link to the file  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbd4bsm0t3zbnds/Law%20Data%20Test.csv?dl=0

Comment: I have a single image to duplicate and rename based on the second column of the CSV. This is just a test CSV. So hopefully, I can choose the image and then it will create a copy with the new name. They are basically dummy images.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[,\r]' 'NR>1{ print "cp "$1".png "$2".png" }' 'Law Data Test.csv' | sh
```

Use comma and carriage return as field separators, skip the header line and print the two fields with a prefixed `cp` and `.png` suffixes. Then pipe the output to sh to execute the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Remove first row and run

```
cat Law\ Data\ Test.csv | sed 's/,/ /g'| sed 's/^/cp /' >temp.sh
source temo.sh
rm temp.sh
```